# Is the any way to identify whether a query is in view or not in react query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

Assume I have 3 queries x, y and z. I want to update the query x only when it is in view. Is there any way to identify it ?

I tried to maintain the view query key as a global state, but it seems not working fine. Is there any way to identify without maintaining viewing query key as global state.

Is there any possible way to get list of viewing queries ???

Comment: What do you mean with update query x

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to hold the state of the component if it's in the viewport or not. The `IntersectionObserver` API allows you to detect when an element enters or leaves the viewport, which you can use to update the state of your component.

Then you can use that state as a key in your useQuery. Also you can use it in `enabled` option if you want to prevent refetch when item is not on the viewport.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

function Test() {
  const [isInViewport, setIsInViewport] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          setIsInViewport(true);
        } else {
          setIsInViewport(false);
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(ref.current);

    return () => {
      observer.unobserve(ref.current);
    };
  }, []);

  useQuery(
    [isInViewport],
    () => (
      /// your query
    ),
    {
      enabled: isInViewport,
    },
  );

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <div>{isInViewport ? 'In viewport' : 'Not in viewport'}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```